# How do i delete a channel in discord.py having its id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do i delete a channel in discord.py having its id?
By channel i mean voice, text and category channels.
I tried with `Guild.channel.delete(channel_id)` but it's not working neither throwing errors

```
@client.command()
async def removechannel(ctx, channel_id):
    removeChannel(channel_id)
```

(`removeChannel` would just delete the channel with its ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the argument type to be a `TextChannel`, you're able to mention it in the command instead of having to write the ID, although the ID will also work - `!removechannel #general`.
The `TextChannel` object has a `delete()` method that you can use like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def removechannel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.delete()
    await ctx.send("Successfully deleted the channel!")
```

You can also make it work via ID if you want (for voice channels, as you can't mention them):

```py
@client.command()
async def removechannel(ctx, channel_id: int):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.delete()
    await ctx.send("Successfully deleted the channel!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`abc.GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) - Returned from `Client.get_channel()`
- [`GuildChannel.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete) - All guild channels (text channels, voice channels, categories) will inherit this method.
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)

Comment: and how do i delete a category channel?

Comment: The `Client.get_channel()` method covers that - if you just enter the category's ID, then it'll work. (Using the second example - the first is purely for text channels)

Comment: for me it dosen't work for category channels  -   (solved)