# Create Discord.py server and delete all channels directly?

Tags: python, discord

I want to create a small Discord Selfbot bot that completely copies a server.

Everything works except that I can't delete the channels on the new server.

Here is a small excerpt:

````
newguild = await client.create_guild(ctx.message.guild.name)
for channel in newguild.channels:
await channel.delete()```
````

Comment: Posts on Stack Overflow [should be in english](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details as of why you can't delete the channels..

Comment: @iLuvLogix There is no error code it's doing nothin

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244869/how-do-i-delete-a-channel-in-discord-py-having-its-id) - and also read the official API-docs linked in the answer

Comment: @iLuvLogix I already looked in the API-docs and the code doesn't work for me because i work with the var newguild and not with anything else.

Comment: and `newGuild.channels.deleteAll` won't do the trick?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: Selfbots are not supported anymore and violate the ToS of Discord. Please avoid asking those kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Self bots are against the Discord TOS, so you should set up a bot account through their website and use a bot account for your bot.